# Python os.system with 2 variables and zip

Tags: python, zip, os.system

Sry, my english skills are very low.

My problem :

I want start a EXE with the "os.system" function.
It works...

```
os.system("Engine\\2.75\\python\\python.exe TEST_GUI.py")
```

So...now. This Code starts the Python EXE and starts my TEST GUI.
But what is to do...when the "TEST GUI.py" is in a ZIP File ?

I want to start the Python.exe with the "TESTGUI.py".
I dont wanna extract the zip file before.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by including a

```
__main__.py
```

file in the zip archive which acts as the entry point to your program.  For example given that creatfile.py contains:

```
def writefile(f):
    fout = open(f, 'wt')
    fout.write('hello world')
    fout.close()
```

and

```
__main__.py
```

contains:

```
from createfile import *

writefile('test1.txt')
```

Then, after putting them in writefile.zip, running

```
os.system('python writefile.zip')
```

causes test1.txt to be created in the current working directory with 'hello world' written to it.

Showing this in IPython:

```
%ls
 Directory of C:\Users\tn\Documents\python\tmp

09/22/2015  11:02 PM    <DIR>          .
09/22/2015  11:02 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/22/2015  10:51 PM                52 __main__.py
09/22/2015  10:50 PM                98 createfile.py
09/22/2015  10:51 PM               422 writefile.zip
           3 File(s)            572 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  304,887,132,160 bytes free

os.system('python writefile.zip')
Out[29]: 0

%ls
 Directory of C:\Users\tn\Documents\python\tmp

09/22/2015  11:02 PM    <DIR>          .
09/22/2015  11:02 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/22/2015  10:51 PM                52 __main__.py
09/22/2015  10:50 PM                98 createfile.py
09/22/2015  11:02 PM                11 test1.txt
09/22/2015  10:51 PM               422 writefile.zip
               4 File(s)            583 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  304,887,132,160 bytes free

!type test1.txt # 'type' is the Windows equivilant of the Linux cat command
hello world

!type createfile.py

def writefile(f):
    fout = open(f, 'wt')
    fout.write('hello world')
    fout.close()

!type __main__.py
from createfile import *

writefile('test1.txt')

!7za l writefile.zip

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Listing archive: writefile.zip

--
Path = writefile.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 422

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2015-09-22 22:50:13 ....A           98           76  createfile.py
2015-09-22 22:51:08 ....A           52           52  __main__.py
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                   150          128  2 files, 0 folders
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import Python modules from a zip file as if it was a directory.

For example, if you have `TEST_GUI.py` inside `TEST_GUI.zip` (just one file, no folders - a simplest case):

```
def main():
    print('Hello world!')
```

you can call it with single shell call as follows:

```
python -c "import sys;import os;sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('TEST_GUI.zip'));import TEST_GUI; TEST_GUI.main()"
```

Let me explain it line by line:

- `python -c` - call Python with a piece of code as an argument
- `import sys;import os;` - import necessary packages
- `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('TEST_GUI.zip'))` - this is where magic happens. ZIP file can be added to `PATH` just like an ordinary folder!
- `import TEST_GUI` - since Python now sees TEST_GUI.py via `PATH` environment variable, we can import it.
- `TEST_GUI.main()` - we call the `main()` function, and it does whatever we want.

Using `os.system` for the same script is straightforward:

```
>>> os.system("python -c \"import sys;import os;sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('TEST_GUI.zip'));import TEST_GUI; TEST_GUI.main()\"")
Hello world!
0
```

However, I recommend you to get rid of `os.system` and use [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) instead.